# JavaScript variable displayed as undefined in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got an HTML page that contains user inputs (dropdowns & textfields). 
These user inputs should be passed through to a JavaScript file where they will then be processed and used inside formulas.
After the inputs are passed through the formulas, they should get passed back to a alternate HTML page as results. On this result page there has to be an option where the results can be emailed using PHP.

I've built the basic model (using Twitter Bootstrap) up until the point where the inputs are stored as JavaScript variables and then these variables get passed through to a JavaScript file called "calculate.js" where all the formulas are being processed.

The problem I'm facing now is getting the formula results to display on the result HTML page, but the formula returns "undefined". And I've been trying to understand why its not working and I don't seem to quite understand what the problem is... Maybe I should change the way I'm storing my input values?

Anyway, below is the basic idea of what my project looks like;

A summary of the HTML, called "index.html":

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="dropdown">Dropdown Input</label><br>
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" class="dropselect">
      <option value="None selected">Please select one</option>
      <option value="95">95</option>
      <option value="75">75</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="text_input">Text Input</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_input" placeholder="Length">
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step" onclick="Submit()">Save and continue</button></li>
</ul>
```

A summary of the JavaScript file, called "main,js":

```
function Submit() {
  document.getElementById('output_user_input').innerHTML =
    "Dropdown Input: " + document.getElementById("dropdown").value + "<br>" +
    "Textfield Input: " + document.getElementById("text_input").value;
}
```

A summary of the Javascript file, called "calculate.js":

```
var variable_1 = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
var variable_2 = document.getElementById("text_input").value;

var formula = (variable_1 * variable_2);
```

Now the formula returns as undefined and I have no idea what the reason for this is. Apologies for the long question, but I had to get you to understand what it is that I need to be done here.

Comment: I'm calling the java after the html. They are on completely different pages, so it shouldn't be that. When you say I should wrap it, should I wrap the variables or the formulas?

Answer (score 0):

One of `variable_1` or `variable_2` must be undefined as well (maybe both); you can use JS debugger or console.log() to find out which one.

First problem seems to be that the `input#text_input` is missing a value (maybe you are entering it manually, but just from the code you posted, it is undefined)

Second, it is good practice to *convert string values to numbers* before you do any arithmetics. JavaScript converts strings to numbers when you try to multiply them, so in this case it would probably work. But if your formula was `variable_1 + variable_2`, the strings would just get concatenated. So you should change it to something like this:

```
var variable_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("dropdown").value);
var variable_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("text_input").value);
```

Take a look at this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/u1jnwLvn/

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I have a bit more inputs than this on my HTML page and some of my formulas consist purely of text input fields, these are also returned as undefined. Do you think my variables aren't declared correctly?

Comment: Before computing any formulas, look at the individual elements and their values.

Comment: OK. I'll do that, maybe I'm just missing some small detail somewhere.

Comment: I edited the answer a lot, seems like the selected value was not an issue... see the fiddle. And please accept this answer if it solved your problem, thanks!